# Python: How to find whether a specific number of items in a list are identical?

Tags: python, arrays, list, poker

I am attempting to create a poker game, and I have a list of values which can be anything from Ace to King in a list (named "number"). In order to determine whether or not the player has a "Four of a Kind", the program needs to check if four items in the list of values are identical.
I have no clue how to do this. Would you somehow use the `number[0] == any in number` function four times, or is it something completely different?

Comment: You are supposed to show a honest attempt, and say why it does not meet your requirement. SO is not a free code writing service...

Comment: Translate names into numbers with a dictionary, this makes comparisons easier. Separate a card into value and suit and keep them as pairs. I found numpy comfortable to simplify comparisons.

Comment: "Four of a Kind" is a hand in poker where you have four cards that have identical values, e.g. four 2s or four Aces.

Comment: When evaluating poker hands, it's always good to start by sorting the hand by rank. That makes a lot of the hand-checking much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing that your *number* variable is a list of 5 elements (five cards) you can probably try something like:

```
from collections import Counter
numbers = [1,4,5,5,6]
c = Counter(numbers)
```

This leverages the [awesome Counter class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). :)

Once you have the counter you can check for what is the number of most common occurencies by doing:

```
# 0 is to get the most common, 1 is to get the number
max_occurrencies = c.most_common()[0][1]   
# this will result in max_occurrencies=2 (two fives)
```

If you also want to know which one is the card that is so frequent you can get both information in one go using tuple unpacking:

```
card, max_occurrencies = c.most_common()[0]
# this will result in card=5, max_occurrencies=2 (two fives)
```

Answer (score 0):

You an also store these counts in a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), and check if the max occurrence is equal to your specific number of items:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def check_cards(hand, count):
    d = defaultdict(int)

    for card in hand:
        rank = card[0]
        d[rank] += 1

    return max(d.values()) == count:
```

Which works as follows:

```
>>> check_cards(['AS', 'AC', 'AD', 'AH', 'QS'], 4) # 4 Aces
True
>>> check_cards(['AS', 'AC', 'AD', '2H', 'QS'], 4) # Only 3 Aces
False
```

Even better is with [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), as shown in [@Gabe's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49094098/python-how-to-find-whether-a-specific-number-of-items-in-a-list-are-identical/49094178#49094178) answer:

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

def check_cards(hand, count):
    return max(Counter(map(itemgetter(0), hand)).values()) == count
```